# using ajax with tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I am working on ROR app , see this: http://niveshi.com/ if you go to the bottom and enter a name into the textbox and click on submit, a new folder is added to the table.

Now I want to do this with ajax so page should not refreshed.I added remote: true to my form tag , new code:

```
<%= form_tag("/new", method: "get", remote: true) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Make A new folder:") %><br>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %><br>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

The controller is Portfolio is this:

```
class PortfolioController < ApplicationController
 def show
   @portfolio=Portfolio.last
   g=Portfolio.new
   @h=g.render(@portfolio)
 end

 ### methid which is actually call new
 def new 
   j=params[:q]
   if(j.length>0)
    portfolio=Portfolio.last
    folder=portfolio.folders
    c={"name"=>j,"stocks"=>[]}
    folder.push(c)
    portfolio.update_attributes(folders:folder)
    #root -url is show only
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "folder made"
   else
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "empty name"
   end
end
```

This is not working.I am new to ajax If anyone could tell what should be next step or any source on net.

Comment: You should show us your controller.

Comment: Okey , see edited code.